# pattern-handling data sets without domain

Tags: sql, .net, design-patterns

I'm looking for a pattern to handle a data set that can vary in size (columns).  entity framework is strongly typed and I want to avoid domains, the data sets are determined at runtime. 
any known patterns out there?

Comment: Are you locked into RDBMS? Because this looks like a classical case for NOSQL like MongoDB and the likes.

Comment: what are good resources to refer to what you are suggesting? I'm just looking for a way to pass data from a source to a destination without knowing the structure, eventually I would use this in an excel plug-in, Excel being the destination.

Comment: yes, locked in rdbms structure

Comment: [MongoDB tutorial for CSharpers](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/)

Comment: I'm not certain mongodb is the best way. I'm just looking for a pattern that passes data around, mostly select statements, without storage

Comment: Could you provide example of the intermediate data (different types) you are taking care of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121265/discussion-between-galenus-and-dirtyw0lf).